# Can I glue vinyl flooring to my bathtub's side panel?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, vinyl-flooring

We’ve just bought our first house, and obviously have very little money at the moment. The bathroom is horrible and we’d like to make some small changes to at least make it look slightly nicer.

As part of that I’d like to take out the old laminate floor, to let the wooden subfloor dry as it has been wet for ages due to a small leak. Afterwards I’d like to put down some cheap vinyl.

The bath side panel, is made out of some horrible brown plastic. Could I just glue my floor vinyl to that to make it look nice and (mosaic) tiled? Would it be possible to do it continuously from the floor with a 90 degree angle at the bottom? Or would two sheets be better for this?

Comment: Just doesn't sound like a good idea, two sheets, silicon the join, done.

Answer (score 1):

You can glue what ever you want to the side of your bathroom tub.  Will it hurt anything?  No.  Will it look good?  Highly debatable.

Answer (score 1):

Bending cheap vinyl tile 90 deg to fit the join between the bath panel and the floor will result in cracks and leaks, and your wooden floor will be wet again.

Lay the vinyl tile on the floor up to the bath panel just as if you thought that brown plastic was *tres chic*. Use recommended adhesive and seal all the joints, tile to tile and tile to plastic.

Then, after that job is finished, use something like contact cement and more vinyl tiles to *decorate* the bath panel to match the floor. If the join between the vinyl floor ant the bath panel is waterproof, you don't have to worry about leaks in the decoration.

You might want to experiment with various contact cements and glues to find one that will hold the tiles but can be removed without damaging the brown plastic. That way, if you don't like the way it comes out, you can undo the decoration and try to paint the panel.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge vinyl flooring manufacturers do not allow glue down directly to the bath panel.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to put leftover floor vinyl on side bath panel, fixing with vinyl double-sided tape, temporarily stapled, trim with craft knife. Easy-peasy, it's no big deal.

[image]